# Where can I get a list of movie titles as well as TV show titles with their episode titles

Tags: dataset, imdb

IMDB has the movie titles for download, but not TV show titles. I was going to just use pyIMDB, but it looks like you can't get all of the data easily, just a couple results similar to your search query. Anyone know where I can get this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

With [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sf.net) you can take the [plain text data files](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) and put them in a SQL database.
The data includes TV series and their episodes.
Please refer to the documentation or ask on the mailing list for more details.

Also, don't forget that the license of the IMDb data is granted only for personal and non-commercial uses.